# group by contains value PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

For an analysis, I have two tables, one containing static data (let's call it `profile`) and one recorded user data per timestamp (lets call it `dynamic`). In `dynamic`, many states are possible as follows:

```
profile_id | timestamp | state
-------------------------------
uuid1      | 2023-12...| state1
uuid1      | 2023-12...| state2
uuid1      | 2023-12...| state2
uuid1      | 2023-12...| state3
uuid1      | 2023-12...| state3
uuid1      | 2023-12...| state4
uuid2      | 2023-12...| state3
uuid2      | 2023-12...| state4
...
```

The states can be grouped and for this example, lets assume that state1 and state2 form group 1 and state3 and state4 form group 2. How would an efficient query look like that provides a boolean value for which profiles have expirienced which state group? I was thinking about a join with a group-by, but cannot seem to find the right syntax for it:

```
select profile.id, profile.some_other_column, sub.has_group1, sub.has_group2
left join (
  select profile_id, exists_in_groupby(state1, state2) as has_group1, 
exists_in_groupby(state3, state4) as has_group2
  from dynamic
  group by profile_id) sub
on sub.profile_id = profile.id
```

What would I use for `exists_in_groupby`? Or is there a more efficient approach? Note that `dynamic` could be very large and that we are running into timeout issues (which is why I am asking). Thanks a lot!

EDIT: Current, too slow approach and inefficient approach

```
select profile.id, profile.some_other_column, 
case 
  when 'state1' in (select state from dynamic where profile_id = profile.id) 
  or 'state2' in (select state from dynamic where profile_id = 
profile.id)
  then 1
  else 0
end as has_group1,
case when 'state3' in (select state from dynamic where profile_id = profile.id) 
  or 'state4' in (select state from dynamic where profile_id = profile.id)
  then 1
  else 0
end as has_group2
left join dynamic
on dynamic.profile_id = profile.id 
group by profile.id
```

Comment: what is your current query where you experience issues? `SELECT DISTINCT profile_id, state FROM dynamic` could be a good start. You can do further transformation outside of SQL.

Comment: I added my current approach which is really inefficient since it queries dynamic a few times. I understand that I could create a separate table with your approach, but since we are displaying this in grafana, all has to happen within SQL and we cannot do stuff outside of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do something like below:

```
select profile.id, profile.some_other_columns, 
    g1.has_group1,
    g2.has_group2
from profile 
left join (select distinct profile_id, 1 as has_group1
    from dynamic
    where state in ('state1', 'state2')) g1 on profile.id = g1.profile_id 
left join (select distinct profile_id, 1 as has_group2
    from dynamic
    where state in ('state3', 'state4')) g2 on profile.id = g2.profile_id
```

the only difference from your output is that it has `null` instead of `0`, it can also be managed if it's a problem in grafana.

Comment: That definitively seems promising. Will try it out and mark as solved if it works